# import variable from another file - preventing code from imported file

Tags: python

I want to import archivepath variable from a.py

File b.py:

```
import os
from a import archivepath
from os.path import dirname, abspath
```

File a.py:

```
def getPath():
    try:
        # Open the key and return the handle object.
        hKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
               "SOFTWARE\\COMODO")
            # Read the value.                      
        result = _winreg.QueryValueEx(hKey, "MachineId)
        # Close the handle object.
        result = result[0]
        return result
        _winreg.CloseKey(hKey)
    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
archive = "C:\path\Archive" 

ID = "94"



path = getPath()
```

Dir = os.path.join(path, "state", ID)

When running b.py getting:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 16, in <module>
    from a import archivepath
  File "C:\Users\user\Downloads\\a.py", line 77, >in <module>
    Dir = os.path.join(path, "state", ID)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 65, in join
    result_drive, result_path = splitdrive(path)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 115, in splitdrive
    if len(p) > 1:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

When i remove Dir line, no errors.

I tried this in b.py:

```
import os
 from a import archivepath
 from os.path import dirname, abspath

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Dir = os.path.join(path, "state", ID)
```

But getting the same error.

How to prevent executing Dir line when importing a.py ?

Comment: What does `print(path)` and `print(posDir)` show? Add them in a.py after the variables are created to make sure they're populated correctly.

Comment: Are you intending for `getPath()` and `posDir` to execute when importing the module?

Comment: All top-level code is executed when you import a module.  If `getPath()` encounters an exception it does not return anything, therefore it returns `None` by default, which then causes an error on the `posDir` line.

Comment: @mooglinux, no, getPath and print(posDir) are not meant to be executed when running b.py

Comment: If you don't intend that code to be executed when the module is imported, put it underneath a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

Comment: @JohnGordon,sorry, where to put it, at the end of `b.py` file ?

Comment: @xerks, you can put it anywhere in the file. Typically, it will be at the bottom of the file. You will enter the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block if and only if you are physically running that file. You will not enter it if you are just importing the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked that you get the desired result from `getPath()`? It's returning `None` because in the `except` clause you are simply printing the exception without returning anything. Every subsequent use of `path` will use `None` instead of the desired return value.

Furthermore `from a import archivepath` executes `a.py`, which does not work properly so it fails to import what you want. Fixing `getPath()` will result in success importing `archivepath`. Additionally if you don't want to execute `getPath()` for `posDir` when importing you can modify `a.py` like this:

```
import os

def getPath():
    try:
        # Open the key and return the handle object.
        hKey = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
               "SOFTWARE\\LogRhythm\scsm")
            # Read the value.                      
        result = _winreg.QueryValueEx(hKey, "HPATH")
        # Close the handle object.
        result = result[0]
        _winreg.CloseKey(hKey)
        return result
    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)
        return "error"
archivepath = "C:\path\Archive" 

MsgSourceID = "94"


def main():
    path = getPath()
    if path is not "error":
        posDir = os.path.join(path, "state", MsgSourceID)
    else:
        print "error encountered"


if __name__== '__main__':
  main()
```